# How do we style a component with multiple components Wrapped in a React Fragment without introducing new wrappers , when we upgrade to Material UI 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React component with multiple components wrapped in a Fragment. When I upgraded to Material UI V5 using codemod, it automatically added a div to wrap the components in Styled Component. and My styles are breaking because there is an extra 'div', how can we avoid this issue and not introduce an extra div , but keep the styles like before.

Old code

```
<>
            {key === '1' && <Box className={classes.item1}>content</Box>}
            {key === '2' && <Box className={classes.item2}>content</Box>}
</>
```

After upgrade using codemod - `npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/jss-to-styled src`

```
// TODO jss-to-styled codemod: The Fragment root was replaced by div. Change the tag if needed.

    const Root = styled('div')((
        {
            theme
        }
    ) => {
    return {
    [`& .${classes.item1}`]: {
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                paddingRight: theme.spacing(1)
            }
    }

    <Root>
                {key === '1' && <Box className={classes.item1}>content</Box>}
                {key === '2' && <Box className={classes.item2}>content</Box>}
    </Root>
```